# How to convert members of a matrix in a specific constrains value in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, constraints

If

```
a =

     1 
     2 
     3
     3.5
     5
     6
     6.25
     8
     9
     9.75
     11
     12
     13
     14
     15
```

How it is possible to switch numbers which are in a specific constrains, into the smaller part of constrain?

In other word, if `b=min(a)` & `c=b+threshold`

`b<a<c` => `a=b`.

It means, in this example, let's assume **threshold=3**. Then `"a"` should change into a matrix which `min(a):min(a)+threshold =[min(a)]`. This procedure should continue to the last array of `"a"`matrix by adding each time the amount of threshold. The result should be like this:

```
a=
    1
    1
    1
    1
    5
    5
    5
    5
    9
    9
    9
    9
    13
    13 
    13
```

Comment: what are `a , b and c` and how they are related to the `threshold` value?

Comment: @Nishant The inquiry has been amended. I hope you will find it more clear. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: at first iteration ,`min(a) = 1` so `b = 1` , `c = 1+3 =  4` . Then all values of a strictly between `b and c` i.e. ` 1 and 4` are converted to 1  resulting in `1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    5.0000    6.0000    6.2500    8.0000    9.0000    9.7500   11.0000   12.0000   13.0000   14.0000   15.0000`. After that I cannot understand your next iterations

Answer (score 0):

[Logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1)

Edit, based on the comment thread

I can't think of a way to avoid a loop here, nor am I really sure how to constrain it efficiently, but the general process is the same:

```
% Initial conditions
threshold = 3;
a = [1 2 3 3.5 5 6 6.25 8 9 9.75 11 12 13 14 15];
b = min(a);
c = b + threshold;

a((a > b & a < c)) = b;

for/while/if % Need some way to constrain the loop
    b = c;
    c = c+threshold;
    a((a > b & a < c)) = b;
end
```

Comment: As you see the first 4 members are min(a) which are desired. However, my question is how we can continue this procedure to the end?
Cheers

Comment: @Iman Then you need to clarify your constraints. As stated, your b, c, and threshold values are static so in the example data set we're never going to look any higher than 4.

Comment: I mean "b" and "c" are increasing in each loop. To be more precise, for  the first loop b=min(a), c=b+threshold. for second loop b=c and c=c+threshold  and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I guess finally I found a solution for that. Sorry if I couldn't explain better my intention and mislead you. Here is the code:

```
a = [1 2 3 3.5 5 6 6.25 8 9 9.75 11 12 13 14 15]';
b = min(a);
threshold=4;
c=b;

for i=1:size(a,1)
    c =c+threshold; 
a((a > b & a < c)) = b;
b=b+threshold;
if c==max(a);
    break
end
end
```

P.S. threshold change to `"threshold=4"` instead of "3"